# Flash/HTML5 based video player that deletes temp files after playing file

Tags: php, flash, html, caching, video-streaming

I'm making video files for my students sharing these files with them via dropbox. What I want to do is, to prevent illegal copy of these files. In other words my service is paid, and currently one person can pay for it then share with others for free. So I want to make my files so that, only the person who paid for it, can view these files. No one else

I'm trying to find secure HTML5 or Flash based web video player (for php based website) that doesn't cache video or deletes after playing it. Reason is, want to prevent source video file download. Is there any free plug-in for this purpose? Any suggestion?

Comment: If you can play it you can copy it. Sorry. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analog_hole

Answer (score 0):

Just use Youtube's [Private Video](http://support.google.com/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=157177) feature. It will prevent all unauthorized ways of downloading / watching video: no downloader or online downloading service will download private video. Do followings:

1. Create youtube account (or signin if you have an account)
2. Upload your video into your Youtube channel
3. Make uploaded video private
4. Invite people to watch this video

Only invited people will see it (in your case your students).

[image]